# Will My Goldfish Survive?

Tags: fish

So, I have one small goldfish (tiny) in a 20litre tank. I am going on holidays for 3 weeks later this year and I was wondering if I got someone to come in and feed him once every week would that be fine. I would also do i big water change the day I leave and the day I come back. If that doesn’t work what should I do.

Answer (score 3):

Should be good, plants in the tank ( duckweed is very good) would
 provide some food. Be careful about someone else feeding , unless they have their own fish. Generally a new person is very likely to overfeed. Try leaving individual food packets so they can just dump one packet instead of using food from a large container.

Comment: Yes, the friends I am talking about are quite close and they have fed my fish before when they were at my house. They also used to have there own fish although I will do what you recommend. I will do reasearch about duckweed. Is it easy to just put it in the tank and just leave it or does it need some sort of special care?

Comment: Duck weed is pretty hardy; however I have found occasionally  it won't grow in a particular tank . In ponds it is vigorous : I net it out and put it in my Koi pond , they prefer it to several other plants .

Comment: Might be worth trying the plant before you go. My (big, old) goldfish can eat through some plants in a couple of days. Maybe your friends could add more plants if needed?